# How to increase a player's velocity the farther a device is tilted?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accelerometer

I am making a platform game for mobile in Unity and I would like to increase the speed of my character the farther he travels along the x-axis, up until a max speed, using the accelerometer.

Right now I have this:

```
void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        Vector2 direction = Vector2.zero;
        direction.x = Input.acceleration.x * horizontalSpeed;

        if ( direction.sqrMagnitude > 1 )
        {
            direction.Normalize();
        }

        direction *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(direction);
    }
```

Currently, the character is always moving at the same speed. How can I increase the character's velocity the farther the device is tilted?

I'm thinking I could measure the position of the accelerometer and as the position changes, I could adjust the speed variable. I just can't figure out how to measure it.

Comment: Please don't use the [unity] tag for Unity 3D. That's what the [unity3d] tag is for. The [unity] tag refers to another Microsoft product.

Comment: P.s. why the normalization of the direction vector? I don't know what kind of values you're getting for your direction.x, but if they are significantly higher than 1, the normalization might well be why you never get any different speed. You're killing its magnitude, which directly affects the final velocity.